# Resourcepack loads textures but not models

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I been trying to use this resourcepack:
https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/texture-packs/speed-racer-boats

The version is Java 1.20.1 and uses forge. The file is in the resourcepack folder, already loaded, and the result is this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/susbh.png)

It's clearly getting getting the textures but not the models. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: I don't have code, this is an installation problem. I have the same problem with every resourcepack I try.